# Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-xml

I am having an error in following xml file. *"Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag LinearLayout"*. I tried the solutions provided in other similar questions also but it didn't work for me. Same error is occurring in 3 lines where `LinearLayout` is used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_top_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name_version"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- A horizontal line -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30px" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/start_stop_button"
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="74dp"
                    android:text="@string/start_server" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/instructions"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="74dp"
                    android:text="@string/instructions_label" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/setup"
                    android:layout_width="74dp"
                    android:layout_height="74dp"
                    android:text="@string/setup_label" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30px" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- A horizontal line -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#666666" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10px" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="2" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/server_status"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
                <!-- A small spacer between the columns -->

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="3sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/server_status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/unknown"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10px" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- A horizontal line -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#666666" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10px" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="2" >

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/my_url_is"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
                <!-- A small spacer between the columns -->

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="3sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ip_address"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/no_url_yet"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/wifi_status"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
                <!-- A small spacer between the columns -->

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="3sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/wifi_status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/unknown"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/last_error_label"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/last_error"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
                <!-- A small spacer between the columns -->

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="3sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/last_error"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/unknown"
                    android:textColor="#ff0000"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10px" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- A horizontal line -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1px"
            android:background="#666666" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <!--
          <TextView android:id="@+id/proxy_header"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/proxy_experimental"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
        -->

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="2" >

            <TableRow>

                <!--
                 <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/proxy_status"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="left"
                />
                -->
                <!-- A small spacer between the columns -->

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="3sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <!-- A small spacer between the columns -->

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="3sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <!-- A small spacer between the columns -->

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="3sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <!-- A small spacer between the columns -->

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="3sp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <!-- A horizontal line -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#666666" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- A horizontal line -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#666666" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/server_log"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/server_log_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/server_log"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#333333" />

        <!-- A horizontal line -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#666666"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/session_monitor"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/session_monitor_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/session_monitor"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#333333"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <!-- A horizontal line -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#666666" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- It's visually pleasing to have some empty space at the bottom -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Please try following:

Remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` from all the places excluding the `ScrollView`. I believe it is sufficient to **inform it to the application once** and in the outermost Layout or View of the xml file.

Comment: It's very odd (and non-conformant) that the parser should reject a duplicate namespace declaration. Which XML parser is this?

Comment: Sir, How to see which parser is being used? I have been using the default parser that came with Eclipse ADT bundle.

Comment: Thanks, leaving the xmlns line in the main linear layout, and removing it from the rest of the nested layouts worked.

Answer (score 43):

I encountered this problem multiple times with various codes.

The codes were running absolutely fine in the past but now they are showing these errors....

I found a very simple solution, doesn't require any code changes (Addition, edit or deletion).

Go to the Project Tab at the tab
Click on the tab
Select the "Clean...." from the list

You will see the list of all the projects opened in your work space.

You can either select one project or all (I generally do "Clean all projects").
Click Ok.
The process takes around 5-7 sec for around 10 projects. 
All the XMLNS errors are resolved...
You should try this before trying any other solution....
This is like restarting the system for Window's error which resolves problems 70% of the times...

The above solution is more of a temp solution working in all situation..
To avoid the situation in future, I all xmlns codes together at the top. (there may be a duplicate statement that may be required to be deleted)

I was having this issue when integrating Admob on the XML file.

Comment: Absolutely. This is the first thing that one should try. Many a times cleaning the project works and some other solution suggest the same. But, it was not working for me even after that and removing that line worked.

Comment: If you even don't want to wait projects cleaning time, open the Problems view in eclispe, select the error coming from the xml namespace and delete them(press Canc or select Delete in the contextual menu). Funny eclipse, isn't it?

Comment: Hello guys, the above solution does not match with me, but this solution is so perfect and it worked fine ... Big Thanks @Sudhir ..

Answer (score 6):

In an Android xml file, the Android namespace can:

- only be declared once
- only be declared in the top ('outer') Android `View` in the xml hierarchy

or you'll receive an error when building the project. In your case, the top Android view is the `ScrollView`, so keep

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

in the `ScrollView`, and remove it from all other nested `Views`, including the `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 4):

for people who suddenly see this message appear, the comment from  `Sudhir` should be the accepted answer.. the English wasn't *that* good I thought : so if you struggle: in eclipse go to `project` menu click `clean...` and pick `clean all projects` this will remove the random appearance of this as a message in a situation where it was missing before

Comment: In my case @Shobhit's answer is correct. Sudhir's recommendation to do a full Clean/Rebuild, although valid, is too obvious for the majority of users.

Comment: I agree with @DavidManpearl, Sudhir's answer is a workaround, Shobhit's one is a permanent solution

Answer (score 1):

I think remove the unneeded line is a more suitable way because:

1) Clean the Project will only resolve the problem once. And if you launch the project again or switch from another file to this xml file, it will show the error again.

2) More importantly, "`xmlns:XXX`" should be the property of the first node.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

remove the above tag

and keep

```
<fragment
..........
........
........
......../>
```

or `</fragment>`

Answer (score 0):

To make this problem disappear once and forever without mass changes in the source (that would introduce noise to version tracking):

Go to the "Problems" tab -- right click on the message -- select "Quick fix".
A window appears where you can tell Eclipse to ignore this problem in the project (or in just one file, if you wish).

After that, the XML will compile ok.