# xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" this line is marked as error in Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

In my XML file, i made a few `LinearLayout`'s, and for some reason I get an error on line : 
`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.
It is marked with red (Error) and the error log says : `"Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag LinearLayout"`

Does somebody know what that means?

Answer (score 7):

1) Only use that in the outermost layout that you have. It is sufficient to specify once. Remove all the other occurrences of it.

see [Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916638/unexpected-namespace-prefix-xmlns-found-for-tag-linearlayout)

Answer (score -1):

if you are working on eclipse just go to Project on menu, and then Clean...error fix :D