# Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag ListView

Tags: android, listview, xml-namespaces

I added a list view under RelativeLayout in activity_main.xml to create a simple list view for the main activity (please excuse me if I am using wrong terminology.  I am very new to android dev).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This worked perfectly for some time.
I am note sure what I did because now I am getting a red error circle on the line 
        `android:id="@+id/listview"`
The error i am getting is: `Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag ListView`

Eclipse wont let me compile the project even though it was just working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916638/unexpected-namespace-prefix-xmlns-found-for-tag-linearlayout?rq=1 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
from  your listview definition, it is only necessary once for the xml file.

```
    <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

xmlns is the namespace you are defining, in this case you are saying at the beginning of the file that "android" is linked to the namespace at

```
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

so there is an error when you are attempting to redefine it

Comment: That's odd... Expecting this, I had removed the line earlier, and the error remained at the line `android:id="@+id/listview"` I switched workspaces and then it magically fixed itself...

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this type of situation in future, I believe it's sufficient to inform the application only once about xml namespace at outermost **Layout** or **View** of xml file.

It's very odd because parser should reject any duplicate namespace declaration.

So you have to remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` from all the spaces (here **ListView**) except outermost Layout/View (here **RelativeLayout**)

OR

You can do a *temporary solution* by cleaning that project. Though it's a temporary solution, the plus point is that *you don't have to do any code changes*.