# error Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml

I have an error "Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag LinearLayout" in "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in LinearLayout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected namespace prefix "xmlns" found for tag LinearLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916638/unexpected-namespace-prefix-xmlns-found-for-tag-linearlayout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for placing `namespace` attribute for every Layout you defined in you `layout.xml` files. Namespace can be defined for a root level element only as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: There might be no need for it, but it's perfectly legal.

Comment: @omer341 do u find the solution??

Comment: @MichaelKay given it's a question about Android, are you sure it's "perfectly legal" for Android's xml parser? This _will_ solve the OP's situation. I tried looking up for official documentation on this (both the W3 spec and Android specific mention) but turned up short.

Comment: @MichaelKay http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html **"A prefix can only be bound to a single Namespace URI in the current scope"** perhaps Android Lint checks only that a prefix is only declared once, and doesn't check the value to see if it's the same.

Comment: @atalum you're quoting from an API spec not an XML spec. If the Android parser had such a serious non-conformance to the XML spec, I'm sure we would have heard about it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

from your `LinearLayout`. You only add that once, in your root `layout`. You can only define a namespace once in each xml

Comment: Wrong, wrong, wrong. You can define a namespace in your XML as often as you like.

Answer (score 0):

The XML appears to be well-formed. You can perhaps circumvent the problems by changing the XML, but that doesn't explain why you are getting the error. I think we need to know more about how you are parsing the XML. Check whether other XML parsers accept it.